# Chase Payment Tech and EUDD

Tags: payment

I am trying to implement the EUDD from Chase Payment Tech, but they have very little docs on this.

I send the following to them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <NewOrder>
        <IndustryType>EC</IndustryType>
        <MessageType>AC</MessageType>
        <BIN>000001</BIN>
        <MerchantID>XXXXXX</MerchantID>
        <TerminalID>001</TerminalID>
        <CardBrand>ED</CardBrand>
        <EUDDCountryCode>DE</EUDDCountryCode>
        <EUDDBankSortCode>12345678</EUDDBankSortCode>
        <AccountNum>8888888888</AccountNum>
        <CurrencyCode>978</CurrencyCode>
        <CurrencyExponent>2</CurrencyExponent>
        <AVSzip>XXXXXX</AVSzip>
        <AVSaddress1>XXXXXXX</AVSaddress1>
        <AVSaddress2>XXXXXXXXXX</AVSaddress2>
        <AVScity>XXXXXXXXXXX</AVScity>
        <AVSstate>XX</AVSstate>
        <AVSname>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</AVSname>
        <AVScountryCode>DE</AVScountryCode>
        <OrderID>94107</OrderID>
        <Amount>4679</Amount>
        <Comments>This a test</Comments>
    </NewOrder>
</Request>
```

This is what I am getting back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <QuickResp>
        <ProcStatus>05</ProcStatus>
        <StatusMsg>Request does not adhere to the DTD. Please correct and send again.</StatusMsg>
    </QuickResp>
</Response>
```

I am using the test url from Chase and test account.

Please could someone advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok for who ever needs to do this, this is correct working version for there API, this answer came from chase payment tech and I tested and works great

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Request>
               <NewOrder>
                     <IndustryType>EC</IndustryType>
                     <MessageType>AC</MessageType>
                     <BIN>000001</BIN>
                     <MerchantID>XXXXXXXXXX</MerchantID>
                     <TerminalID>001</TerminalID>
                     <CardBrand>ED</CardBrand>
                     <AccountNum>8888888888</AccountNum>
                     <CurrencyCode>978</CurrencyCode>
                     <CurrencyExponent>2</CurrencyExponent>
                     <AVSzip>XXXXXXXXXXX</AVSzip>
                     <AVSaddress1>XXXXX</AVSaddress1>
                     <AVSaddress2>XXXXXXX</AVSaddress2>
                     <AVScity>XXXXXXXXXX</AVScity>
                     <AVSstate></AVSstate>
                     <AVSname>XXXXXXXXXXX</AVSnme>
                     <AVScountryCode></AVScountryCode>
                     <OrderID>94107</OrderID>
                     <Amount>4679</Amount>
                     <Comments>This a test</Comments>
                     <EUDDCountryCode>DE</EUDDCountryCode>
                     <EUDDBankSortCode>12345678</EUDDBankSortCode>
               </NewOrder>
        </Request>
```

Comment: Me too have same issue. I tested with this code. But not success. Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks